# Как задать несколько аргументов для одного параметра функции в C++?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Я новичок в С++ (намёк, что-бы не ругались), и мне нужно написать функцию, в которой неограниченное количество аргументов (параметров), я знаю, что в JavaScript есть такая штуковина `function func(...args){}`, и эти элементы (...args) передаются в массив args[]. Как организовать такое в С++?

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться (при однотипных параметрах) массивом (в С++ - лучше вектором).

Если параметры разнотипные - использовать [функции с переменным количеством параметров](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) и соответствующие языковые возможности. Поскольку непонятно, что именно вам подойдет - дать полный  развернутый ответ вряд ли получится (уж очень много писать надо :))

Comment: Язык Си типовый. Если несколько аргументов одного типа, то просто создаёте массив, и его адрес передаёте. А если разных типов, то надо подходить индивидуально, скажите какие типы аргументов нужны и ваши попытки покажите.

Comment: Можно передать `std::vector<std::any>`, но это неправильно. Не надо делать, как в JavaScript.

Comment: Если аргументы  константы, то лучше подойдет  template<typename T>
std::initializer_list<T> args